# Can't login with Apple Id - Keycloak

Tags: keycloak, apple-id

I am configuring Keycloak login with Apple Id I followed the steps according to these pages:
https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/06/04/what-the-heck-is-sign-in-with-apple and https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/sign-in-with-apple/119/4

But when I try to login, the following is returned:
[pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncISq.png)

Here is my configuration:
[pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0TWI.png)

I don't understand where I went wrong, please help

Comment: https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/sign-in-with-apple/119

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I configured apple SSO using below link

https://github.com/BenjaminFavre/keycloak-apple-social-identity-provider

Just download the latest provider jar file and copy it to Keycloak->standalone->deployments folder. Add Apple IDP on Keycloak identity provider list and according to the documentation add Client-ID, Client secret, Team ID, Key ID and default scopes.

Please make sure you have provided the correct redirect uri, client id as com.XXXX.XXXXXX (in my case com.renter.applesso), Client secret should not have new line and delimiters, Key ID and Team ID (Should be 10 character) and default scope has to pass without space and comma

I had these error while configuring apple SSO with Keycloak unexpected error when authenticating with identity provider, invalid-client, invalid-grant, Internal server error, could not decode access token. This is due to ClientID, client secret, Key ID and Team ID mistakes. So double check all values.

This Solution is 100% working for me..

Comment: What version of keycloak are you using? I am trying to do the same on version 18.1.1 installed via an helm chart and I get the following error when I copy provider jar to the `deployments` folder `deployment content /opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/deployments/apple-social-identity-provider-1.0.2.jar appears to be incomplete and is not progressing toward completion. This content cannot be auto-deployed`

Comment: My mistake above was to curl the file without using the right options. This works for me `curl -LO https://github.com/BenjaminFavre/keycloak-apple-social-identity-provider/releases/download/v1.0.2/apple-social-identity-provider-1.0.2.jar`